# trying to build a Camunda developer workflow with camunda tomcat container image but the bpmns don't show up on the camunda dashboard on ECS Fargate

Tags: tomcat, camunda

I have a skeleton project created from start.camunda.com and I have added a bpmn into the resources folder but when I bundle this into a war and deploy on ECS Fargate, I do not see the BPMN appearing on the Camunda Dashboard. I am exploring how to build workflows and deploy them into ECS Fargate. So far the ECS Task fronted by ALB shows no new BPMNs. I only see the example BPMNs that come with the container image.

the Dockerfile looks like this:-

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:tomcat-7.18.0

COPY ./target/workflow-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war /camunda/webapps/

EXPOSE 8080
```